# Interpret C++ argv[] as relationship between variables with CERN's ROOT

Tags: c++, argv, root-framework

I want to be able to call a function with a variable or combination of variables in the command line, like:

```
$ ./myFunction.exe "var1"
```

or

```
$ ./myFunction.exe "var1/var2"
```

Later in my script, I define a variable **float VAR** which should be defined according to the user input. For the first case, I want:

```
float VAR = var1;
```

...and for the second case, I want:

```
float VAR = var1/var2;
```

Is there a way in CERN's ROOT framework to interpret this user-defined character array as a relationship between variable names like this? I realize this is a stretch, but right now I need to hard-code this each time I want to change VAR, and I'd prefer to not have to do that.

Note that these variables are named in a TTree which I read in from an external *.root file, so I was thinking there may be a way to define **VAR** using gROOT->ProcessLine(), but I haven't been able to figure it out. I understand that this is impossible in straight C++, but I feel like this should be possible with ROOT.

Comment: Can't you just parse the operation and do it like you would with a calculator?

Comment: What do you mean "parse the operation"? If it were a number like a float or an int, I could use std::atof or std::atoi, respectively, but these are names of variables in my script, not numbers or strings or anything.

Comment: Well you would need a map or something like it that you can map a string to the variable the string represents and then you can substitute the values once you parse the string.

Comment: Parsing goes well beyond simple calls to `std::atoi`. It means you read a string, figure out what it means (what operations it requires, and if they are legal), and than have your program execute them.

Comment: Ah, okay. See my edits. I assume that there's a way to do this in CERN's ROOT framework such that I don't have to create a map like this and write my own parsing algorithm. But I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: It is aconventional to call C++ code a script.  If the variable names are only known at run time, you're not going to be able to do it — without rerunning the compiler or something equally dramatic.  If the variable names are fixed at compile time but the combinations can be adjusted at runtime, you'll have to parse the expression and evaluate it — and you'll have to know how to associate a variable name in a string with variables in the binary.  You might be able to use `dlopen()` and `dlsym()` on a POSIX-ish system, but the implications are not nice.

Comment: See edits. I understand that what I want to do isn't possible in straight C++, but it feels like this should be within the scope of ROOT.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ROOT comes indeed with a C++ interpreter, so ROOT scripts are usually called scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to pass only arithmetic expressions into your routine. If so, here is an alternative solution using ROOT's TFormula (in ROOT6):

```
#include <iostream>

#include "TFormula.h"
#include "TString.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   TFormula my_formula("my_formula", TString(argv[argc-1]) );

   my_formula.SetParNames("var1", "var2");
   my_formula.SetParameter("var1", 3.45678);
   my_formula.SetParameter("var2", 8.76543);

   // The formula does not define any variable so input to TFormula::Eval() is
   // irrelevant
   double dummy = 0;

   std::cout << "my_formula: " << my_formula.GetExpFormula("clingp") << "\n"
             << "result:     " << my_formula.Eval(dummy) << std::endl;

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The caveat is that you need to wrap your variables in square brackets `[]` like this:

```
$ ./myFunction.exe "[var1]/[var2]"
$ ./myFunction.exe "[var1]"
$ ./myFunction.exe "[var1]/[var2]+[var1]*[var2]"
```

That's the notation for TFormula's parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Are you on ROOT 5 or 6? For me this works on ROOT 5.34:

In `test.cpp`

```
double x = 2;
double y = 3;
double z;

void test(const char* arg)
{
  gROOT->ProcessLine(TString("z=")+arg);
  cout << z << endl;
}
```

In ROOT shell:

```
.x test.cpp("x/y")
```

Output:

```
0.666667
```

What does not work is having `x` and `y` as local variables in `test()`, this results in

```
Error: Symbol x is not defined in current scope
Error: Symbol y is not defined in current scope
```

The variable `z` in this example is also created in global scope, so it seems the `ProcessLine` function runs in global scope, not in the scope of the calling function.

Comment: This is great, but it's about halfway to what I'd like to do. I don't want to have to run in a ROOT shell. I'd like to be able to compile and then run the *.exe.

Comment: With slight modification (see edit) this also runs in compiled mode for me, called with `.x test.cpp+("x/y")`